# My Wisteria was pale

Tags: wisteria

I have a large Wisteria vine that grows on an arbor. Last fall I cut it back significantly.

This spring the blossoms were small and pale, not the brilliant violet they usually are.

What would cause the blossoms to be pale?

Comment: How close to the ground did you cut it back?

Comment: @Bamboo LOL. Pretty much sums up the problem with SE.

Answer (score 1):

If you cut it back too far down, you may have compromised or killed off the grafted part - that would mean what is growing is off the rootstock, which will be wisteria, but not the variety you bought, and which would have smaller, pale flowers. That is why I asked how far down you cut it...

Answer (score 0):

Pale and small flowers usually means the plant was stressed; though also signs of a sulfur deficiency the leaves would be distorted as well in that case.